# Button does not appear on the table

Tags: php, html, sql

The following code adds a Accept/Decline Button per row. But for some reason, the decline button does not appear. I dont know whats wrong. Been stuck for a while now. Help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

```
<?php
                    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","rabco");
                    // Check connection
                    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                    {
                    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                    }

                    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM service_request");


                    echo "<table border='1'>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Service ID</th>
                    <th>Service Type</th>
                    <th>Schuduled Date</th>
                    <th>Scheduled Time</th>
                    <th>Client Reference
                    <th>Client ID</th>
                    <th>Admin ID</th>
                    <th>Special Instructions</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Approve</th>
                    <th>Decline</th>
                    </tr>";

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Service_ID'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Service_type'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Sched_date'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Sched_time'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Client_reference'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Client_IDN'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Admin_IDN'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Special_instructions'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Request_status'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='approve.php?Service_ID=".$row['Service_ID'].">Approve</a></td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='decline.php?Service_ID=".$row['Service_ID'].">Decline</a></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    echo "</table>";

                    mysqli_close($con);
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the closing quotes on your `href` attributes, which is creating malformed HTML output.

You need to change:

```
echo "<td><a href='approve.php?Service_ID=".$row['Service_ID'].">Approve</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='decline.php?Service_ID=".$row['Service_ID'].">Decline</a></td>";
```

to

```
echo "<td><a href='approve.php?Service_ID=".$row['Service_ID']."'>Approve</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='decline.php?Service_ID=".$row['Service_ID']."'>Decline</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing closing quote here:

```
echo "<td><a href='approve.php?Service_ID=".$row['Service_ID'].">Approve</a></td>";
```

Change to:

```
echo "<td><a href='approve.php?Service_ID=".$row['Service_ID']."'>Approve</a></td>";
```

Comment: I am surprised you unaccepted my answer 6 months after date. Was there an issue?